# If Codeigniter controller ID is invalid, how to redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, redirect, controller

I'm hoping the title accurately describes what I'm trying to ask...

My controller uses the third segment of a url (intId) to search my database for database information to load in its view pages etc. And it works fine, providing the intId corresponds to a row in my database... However, if some rogue decides to enter a random intId, the page loads with errors because naturally the required variables in the view files are not set if the intId does not exist.

In my Controller, how do I set and if statement to determine if the intId is valid, and if not - set a redirect to an error page etc.

```
<?php
class Brands extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Products_model');
    }
    public function products_lookup_by_id($intId)
    {
        $config = array(
            'base_url' => base_url() . '/brands/' . $intId . '/',
            'total_rows' => $this->Products_model->total_rows_brands($intId),
            'per_page' => 25,
            'uri_segment' => 3
        );
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data         = array(
            'offset_no' => $this->uri->segment(3),
            'total_rows' => $config['total_rows'],
            'per_page' => $config['per_page'],
            'nav1' => $this->Products_model->nav1(),
            'nav2' => $this->Products_model->nav2(),
            'nav3' => $this->Products_model->nav3(),
            'nav4' => $this->Products_model->nav4(),
            'nav5' => $this->Products_model->nav5(),
            'nav6' => $this->Products_model->nav6(),
            'nav7' => $this->Products_model->nav7()
        );
        if ($data['total_rows'] > 0)
        {
            $data['from'] = $data['offset_no'] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $data['from'] = 0;
        }
        if (($data['total_rows'] - $data['offset_no']) < $data['per_page'])
        {
            $data['to'] = ($data['offset_no'] + ($data['total_rows'] - $data['offset_no']));
        }
        else
        {
            $data['to'] = $data['offset_no'] + $data['per_page'];
        }
        $query = $this->Products_model->query_brands($intId);
        foreach ($query as $row)
        {
            $data['title']     = $row['my_brand'];
            $data['description']   = $row['description'];
            $data['breadcrumb'] = $row['my_brand'];
            $data['images']     = 'brands/' . $row['intId'];
        }
        $data['section_page']      = 'Brands';
        $data['section_page_link'] = 'brands';
        $data['items1']            = $this->Products_model->items1_brands($data['per_page'], $data['offset_no']);
        $this->template->load_header('products/header_view', $data);
        $this->template->load_mainview('products/mainview_view', $data);
        $this->template->load_grid('products/grid_view', $data);
        $this->template->load_footer('footer_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function products_lookup_by_id($intId)
    {
        $config = array(
            'base_url' => base_url() . '/brands/' . $intId . '/',
            'total_rows' => $this->Products_model->total_rows_brands($intId),
            'per_page' => 25,
            'uri_segment' => 3
        );

        if (empty($config['total_rows'])) {

            redirect('/errors');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate `total_rows` value, add below code after `$config` initialization

```
if (empty($config['total_rows'])) {
    // redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your $this->Products_model->total_rows_brands($intId) function :

```
function total_rows_brands($intId)
{
     if (! is_numeric($intId)) {
          return FALSE;
     }

     $query = $this->db->get_where('your_table', array('id' => $intId));

     if (! $query) {
          return FALSE;
     }

     .... 
}
```

And then in your controller :

```
public function products_lookup_by_id($intId)
{
     $data = $this->Products_model->total_rows_brands($intId);

     if (! $data) {
         redirect('your_500_error_controller');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

load->model('Products_model');
    }
    public function products_lookup_by_id($intId)
    {
        $config = array(
            'base_url' => base_url() . '/brands/' . $intId . '/',
            'total_rows' => $this->Products_model->total_rows_brands($intId),
            'per_page' => 25,
            'uri_segment' => 3
        );

```
     ############# This code for $intId record check ####
   $productRecord = $this->Products_model->total_rows_brands($intId);
```

if(!count($productRecord)>0) {
       $heading = "404 Page Not Found"; 
          $message = "The page you requested was not found.";
         // show_error($heading, $message);
          show_error($message, 500, $heading);
      }

############# End of product record check code ###

```
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data         = array(
        'offset_no' => $this->uri->segment(3),
        'total_rows' => $config['total_rows'],
        'per_page' => $config['per_page'],
        'nav1' => $this->Products_model->nav1(),
        'nav2' => $this->Products_model->nav2(),
        'nav3' => $this->Products_model->nav3(),
        'nav4' => $this->Products_model->nav4(),
        'nav5' => $this->Products_model->nav5(),
        'nav6' => $this->Products_model->nav6(),
        'nav7' => $this->Products_model->nav7()
    );
    if ($data['total_rows'] > 0)
    {
        $data['from'] = $data['offset_no'] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $data['from'] = 0;
    }
    if (($data['total_rows'] - $data['offset_no']) < $data['per_page'])
    {
        $data['to'] = ($data['offset_no'] + ($data['total_rows'] - $data['offset_no']));
    }
    else
    {
        $data['to'] = $data['offset_no'] + $data['per_page'];
    }
    $query = $this->Products_model->query_brands($intId);
    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
        $data['title']     = $row['my_brand'];
        $data['description']   = $row['description'];
        $data['breadcrumb'] = $row['my_brand'];
        $data['images']     = 'brands/' . $row['intId'];
    }
    $data['section_page']      = 'Brands';
    $data['section_page_link'] = 'brands';
    $data['items1']            = $this->Products_model->items1_brands($data['per_page'], $data['offset_no']);
    $this->template->load_header('products/header_view', $data);
    $this->template->load_mainview('products/mainview_view', $data);
    $this->template->load_grid('products/grid_view', $data);
    $this->template->load_footer('footer_view', $data);
}
```

}